# Trying to sign out from Firebase Auth and Google

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

So, my problem is that when i log out from firebase i cant see the log in window with the different accounts pop up again after i press login

So i found that we need to logout from google api, here is my code how i do it but i get an error

This is inside my button `onClick`

```
 Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                             @Override
                             public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                                 FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                                 finish();
                             }
                         });
```

and i get this error

> 'android.content.Context
>   com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.getContext()' on a
>   null object reference

at this line

```
 Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).......
```

any idea what is going on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use `mGoogleApiClient.connect();` and then just check `Auth.GoogleSignInApi` for nullity:

```
if (Auth.GoogleSignInApi != null) {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
         @Override
         public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
             FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
             finish();
         }
     });
}
```

Comment: the problem was i needed to start mGoogleApiClient.connect(); in my onstart method