# Android Firebase Gmail Log out

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase to log in users using their Google accounts. On my phone I have three Gmail account so when I press Google sign in button (which is in SignInActivity.java which is activity that is always opened first) I am given an option to chose between those three accounts, I pick one and I am logged in my app. I have added the button to log out current user and it does this:

```
FirestoreUtil.firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener { firebaseAuth ->
            if(firebaseAuth.currentUser == null){
                Log.i("logout", "logout complete current user = null")
                val intent = Intent(mContext, SignInActivity::class.java)
                intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                startActivity(intent)
                activity?.finish()
            }else{
                Log.i("logout", "current user != null = ${firebaseAuth.currentUser}")
            }
        }
        FirestoreUtil.firebaseAuth.signOut()
```

I call `firebaseAuth.signOut()` and use a listener to know when user has been successfully logged out, I then create an Intent with `SignInActivity.java` (which is the main activity that has google signin button) and I put some flags to clear tasks and I start new activity and finish current.

This gives me the weirdest behaviour:

1. First of all when I am returned to SignInActivity and I press
   GoogleSignIn button I don't get the option to choose between three
   account that I have, instead I am logged back in with the account I
   used previously (The point of logout is you choose different account
   not the same ! )
2. Another problem is that after I press logout button I am returned
   back to SignInActivity, but if I then exit the app and come back I am
   sometimes returned back as logged user and sometimes I am show that
   same login screen with sign in button, I don't know what is wrong
   with that

Does anyone know what is happening, am I doing the logout process wrong (I use the same functions from official documentation), why am I not getting the option to choose between accounts, what can be the cause of the weird behaviour when I am sometimes logged automatically and sometimes not.

Comment: Share the code of your signOut listener

Comment: When you sign out from Firebase, the user stays signed into the Google. And next time you then tell Firebase to sign in, it detects the Google sign in and uses that account automatically. To prevent this, you'll also need to explicitly sign out from Google. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47775239/trying-to-sign-out-from-firebase-auth-and-google and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56097948/after-once-login-with-google-authentication-in-my-android-app-i-cant-sign-out

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Should I use googleSignInClient or googleApiClient to sign out, some examples are using first and some second. What is the difference, and should I call firebaseAuth.signOut() before google signOut